# Record is not creating in another model while creating a record in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

Currently i am creating a custom module, in which i need to create a demo record while a customer invoice is created.

This is my custom model.

```
class csm(models.Model):   
    _name= 'csm'
    invoice_date = fields.Datetime('Invoice date',readonly=True)
    delivery_date = fields.Datetime('Delivery date',readonly=True)
```

In account.invoice i have added as,

```
class invoice_csm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    delivery_date = fields.Datetime('Delivery date')
    date_invoice= fields.Datetime('Invoice date')

    @api.multi
    def write(self,values):
         record = super(invoice_csm, self).write(values)
         if self.state == 'paid':
             if self.delivery_date and self.installation_date:
                 self.env['csm'].write({
                     'invoice_date': record .date_invoice,
                     'delivery_date': record .delivery_date,
                     })
        return record
```

What i want is when the status of customer invoice is become paid, i need to create a record in my csm model. But it is not creating. But if i use directly create function then record is creating in csm, but the condtion state=='paid' wont work because we can change the state even after creating invoice. That's why i used write method, but here it is not creating the record.

(Delivery and invoice dates have values)

```
       ############ CODE FOR REFERENCE  #########

class customer(models.Model):
    _name = "csm"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']


    name = fields.Char(string='Subject', required=True)


                            ##   RETAIL   ##

    invoice_date = fields.Datetime('Invoice date',readonly=True)
    delivery_date = fields.Datetime('Delivery date',readonly=True)
    installation_date = fields.Datetime('Installation date',readonly=True)
    service1_date = fields.Datetime('First service date',readonly=True)
    service2_date = fields.Datetime('Second service date',readonly=True)
    service3_date = fields.Datetime('Third service date',readonly=True)



    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        if self.pool['res.users'].has_group(self._cr, self.env.user.id, 'customer_service_management.group_managerz'):
            pass
        elif self.create_uid == self.env.user:
            pass
        else:
            if self.create_uid != self.env.user:
                raise Warning('You are not authorized to delete this record. Contact administrator/manager')
        return super(customer, self).unlink()
```

INVOICE

```
class invoice_csm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'


    delivery_date = fields.Datetime('Delivery date')
    installation_date = fields.Datetime('Installation date')
    service1_date = fields.Datetime('First service date')
    service2_date = fields.Datetime('Second service date')
    service3_date = fields.Datetime('Third service date')



    @api.multi
    def write(self,values):
        record = super(invoice_csm, self).write(values)
        if 'state' in values and values['state'] == 'paid':
            self.env['csm'].create({
                'name': values['number'],
                'delivery_date': values['delivery_date'],
                'installation_date': values['installation_date'],
                'service1_date': values['service1_date'],
                'service2_date': values['service2_date'],
                'service3_date': values['service3_date'],
            })
        return record
```

Comment: Not sure about this: You could try to check values for state like `if 'state' in values and values['state'] == 'paid':` for the case that some other module overrides the models write but is executed after yours. Without concrete Call Order its troublesome tho, for cases where the write should raise an error.

Comment: @makadev. In account.invoice, they are using a function like this  
    def confirm_paid(self):
        return self.write({'state': 'paid'}). While cliking make payment button this function will execute. Is this the problem

Comment: @AKHIL  self.write({'state': 'paid'})  will also finally called your def write(self,values), one more thing you are using self.env['csm'].write use create instead of write

Comment: @PrakashSharma. So what change i need to make here?

Comment: i have posted the answer use self.env['csm'].create

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49779590/9631547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self.env['csm'].create` , instead of `self.env['csm'].write`:

```
@api.multi
def write(self,values):
     record = super(invoice_csm, self).write(values)
     if 'state' in values and values['state'] == 'paid':
         if values.get('date_invoice') and values.get('delivery_date'):
             self.env['csm'].create({
                 'invoice_date': values['date_invoice'],
                 'delivery_date': values['delivery_date'],
                 })
    return record
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is giving error like this in  write
ValueError: ""'bool' object has no attribute 'delivery_date'" while evaluating
u'confirm_paid()'" while evaluating
u'proforma_voucher()'

Comment: when i checked, record has a boolean value and it is showing that  boolean value has no attribute 'delevery_date'. When i use create instead of write as record = super(invoice_csm,self).create(values) there is no problem

Comment: as write return true/Flase thus record is Bool instead of record .delivery_date use values['delivery_date'] as i have update my answer above

Comment: I tried adding 'invoice_date':values['date_invoice'] but it is giving error like ValueError: ""date_invoice" while evaluating. But when i explicitly givien a date field its creating record. What may be the problem?

Comment: only after watching model of "csm" we can say anything, probably post a question which the all code/log/error for reference

Comment: Ok I will post here itself