# i want to add a new field to an existing module odoo11 but i don't know why it didn't work

Tags: python, odoo

## product_template.xml

## the view to add the customizing field to the product module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>

    <data>

        <record id="product_template_only_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">

            <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>

            <field name="model">product.template</field>

            <field name="inherit_id" 

               ref="product.product_template_only_form_view " />

            <field name="arch" type="xml">

               <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="after">

                  <field name="list_price"/>

               </xpath>

            </field>

        </record>

    </data>

</odoo>
```

## models file python

## product_template.py

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields , api

from odoo.addons import decimal_precision as dp

from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError, RedirectWarning, except_orm

from odoo.tools import pycompat

class ProductTemplate(models.Model):

_inherit = 'product.template'

```
_name = 'product.template'

_columns={

    'remise': fields.float('remise du fournisseur', size=10, required=True),

    'marge': fields.float('marge', size=10, required=True),

    'total_reste': fields.float('Reste', size=10, required=True),

}

  remise = fields.float('remise du fournisseur', size=10, required=True)
```

Comment: Please read [guide on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your question according to it (question in a title is a bad practice). Also please provide [clear and complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and error message if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the same field list_price after list_price, you should replace the field that is inside the xpath by the field you want.

```
<record id="product_template_only_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">

    <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>

    <field name="model">product.template</field>

    <field name="inherit_id" 

       ref="product.product_template_only_form_view " />

    <field name="arch" type="xml">

       <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="after">

          <field name="your_custom_field"/>

       </xpath>

    </field>

</record>
```

Comment: i put  it just to see if it works , my xml works just with existing field in same view if i put my custom field (remise) an error occur i don't know what's the problem with my python model

Comment: can you look at my .py model to see if there is a problem in it

Answer (score 0):

```
enter <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

<record id="product_template_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">

    <field name="name">product.template.product.tree</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <tree string="Product">

            <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
            <field name="default_code"/>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="list_price"/>
            <field name="standard_price"/>
            <field name="categ_id"/>
            <field name="type"/>
            <field name="uom_id" options="{'no_open': True, 'no_create': True}" groups="product.group_uom"/>

            <field name="active" invisible="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="product_template_only_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">

    <field name="name">product.template.product.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="8" />
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="name">Product Template</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <field name="categ_id" position="after">

            <field name="default_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('product_variant_count', '>', 1)]}"/>

            <field name="barcode" attrs="{'invisible': [('product_variant_count', '>', 1)]}"/>
        </field>

        <button name="toggle_active" position="before">

            <button name="%(product.product_variant_action)d" type="action"
                icon="fa-sitemap" class="oe_stat_button"
                attrs="{'invisible': [('product_variant_count', '&lt;=', 1)]}"
                groups="product.group_product_variant">
                <field string="Variants" name="product_variant_count" widget="statinfo" />

            </button>
        </button>

        <xpath expr="//page[@name='general_information']" position="after">

            <page name="variants" string="Variants" groups="product.group_product_variant">

                <field name="attribute_line_ids" widget="one2many_list" context="{'show_attribute': False}">

                    <tree string="Variants" editable="bottom">

                        <field name="attribute_id"/>

                        <field name="value_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create_edit': True}" domain="[('attribute_id', '=', attribute_id)]" context="{'default_attribute_id': attribute_id}"/>

                    </tree>
                </field>
                    <p class="oe_grey">
                    <strong>Warning</strong>: adding or deleting attributes
                    will delete and recreate existing variants and lead
                    to the loss of their possible customizations.
                </p>
            </page>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

<record id="product_template_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">

    <field name="name">Product.template.product.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban>

            <field name="id"/>
            <field name="image_small"/>
            <field name="lst_price"/>
            <field name="product_variant_count"/>
            <field name="product_variant_ids"/>
            <field name="currency_id"/>
            <templates>

                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                        <div class="o_kanban_image">
                            <img t-att-src="kanban_image('product.template', 'image_small', record.id.raw_value)"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                            <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <small t-if="record.default_code.value">[<field name="default_code"/>]</small>
                            </strong>
                            <div t-if="record.product_variant_count.value &gt; 1" groups="product.group_product_variant">
                                <strong>
                                    <t t-esc="record.product_variant_count.value"/> Variants
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                            <div name="tags"/>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Price: <field name="lst_price" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id', 'field_digits': True}"></field></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div name="tags"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="product_template_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">

    <field name="name">Products</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="product_template_kanban_view"/>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_sell":1}</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to define a new product.
        </p><p>
            You must define a product for everything you sell, whether it's a physical product, a consumable or a service you offer to customers.
        </p><p>
            The product form contains information to simplify the sale process: price, notes in the quotation, accounting data, procurement methods, etc.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>

 <!-- inherit the product form view -->
 <record id="view_product_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="after">
        <field name="x_remise1"/>
        <field name="x_marge1"/>
    </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

code here

Comment: i've created the field from the interface and used it in the xml view in my custom module

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the error that shows you when you put your fields? 
check the **init**.py files of your module.

Comment: the init.py file is fine i've imported the models

Answer (score 0):

Le champ `remise` n'existe pas

Contexte de l'erreur :

Vue `product.template.common.form`

[view_id: 676, xml_id: mymodulee.view_product_form, model: product.template, parent_id: 328]

None" while parsing file:/c:/program%20files%20(x86)/odoo%2011.0/server/odoo/addons/mymodulee/views/product_template_view.xml:123, near

```
        <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="after">

        <field name="x_remise1"/>
        <field name="x_marge1"/>
        <field name="remise" on_change="onchange_calculer(x_marge1,standard_price)"/>

    </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that within the folder, the models have another init and the one that correctly enters the file that contains the class
Try it ,  :

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

     remise = fields.Float('remise du fournisseur', size=10, required=True)
     marge = fields.Float('marge', size=10, required=True)
     total_reste = fields.Float('Reste', size=10, required=True)
```

P.d: The _columns attribute is from old api v7

Comment: i did it , but still no output in the database :/

Comment: plz check this if you could help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876166/how-to-apply-a-default-calcul-to-the-list-price-field-product-odoo-v11